# Date comparison in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, between, date-comparison

I am trying to compare dates, but my query doesnot return any result. 
Curious if I have written the query correctly ?

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b               
WHERE
CONVERT(varchar(50),a.BirthDate, 101) between CONVERT(varchar(50),b.minage, 101) and CONVERT(varchar(50),b.maxage, 101)
```

Is there anything wrong with this date comparison query ??

Table structure is as :

```
Table a:
Column Name     Datatype
Birthdate       Date

Table b's row:
Column Name     Datatype
minage          Date - calculated as : select DATEADD(year, -41, GETDATE())
maxage          Date - calculated as : select DATEADD(year, -21, GETDATE())
```

In table B, Minage, maxage criteria changes for each row. So range can be as minage 0 max age 20, minage 50 maxage 60 etc.(range not overlapping though).

Any idea on what might be wrong in the query ?

I need to compare/calculate only with date not hours or minutes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be stupid of me.

Looks like I had to reverse order of minage and maxage.

so the below query works:

SELECT *
FROM a, b
WHERE
CONVERT(varchar(50),a.BirthDate, 101) between CONVERT(varchar(50),b.maxage, 101) and CONVERT(varchar(50),b.minage, 101)

Comment: You should **not** use varchars for comparing date values. Use `CAST(tbl.ColName AS Date)` if you need to strip the time part.

Comment: @Magnus : Do you still think my initial query will work if I use CAST instead of CONVERT ? You just gave a suggestion not solution to my problem actual problem... :) I can implement suggestions only when my query works. Thanks for your help!   
If you can provide me a reason supporting your suggetsion that would allow me to better understand functionality. I used varchar after I read in some blogs suggesting use of varchar for date comparison using BETWEEN clause. They never gave a reason and so did not u. Please provide some more info, so I have a reason to move with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I used CONVERT to keep date format constant before comparison. Convert(date, tbl.colname, 101) can be a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert your `date` to `string`. Doing it may cause invalid comparison by string and by date.

```
... WHERE a.BirthDate between b.minage and b.maxage
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the converts (to varchar)

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b               
WHERE
a.BirthDate between b.minage and b.maxage
```

if you need to remove the `Time` part of a `DateTime` you can do: `CAST(a.BirthDate AS Date)`